Spring Cloud config Client Vault token auto renewal
Token generated using specific policy has ttl of 768hr. How to generate token with no expiry or how to renew the token automatically without manual intervention?
spring:
  application:
    name: application
  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:8888/config/
  cloud:
    config:
      token: s.token
  profiles:
    active: default

spring.cloud.vault:
  config.lifecycle:
    enabled: true
    min-renewal: 300s
    expiry-threshold: 4m
    refresh-before-expiry: 50s
    lease-endpoints: Legacy


spring:
application:
    name: configservice
cloud:
    config:
        server:
            git:
                uri: https://github.com/{application}-config
                skip-ssl-validation: true
                username: ${GITHUB_USERNAME}
                password: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
                order: 2
           prefix: /config
            vault:
                host: 127.0.0.1
                port: 8200
                scheme: http
                backend: secret
                skip-ssl-validation: false
                kvVersion: 2
                defaultKey:
                namespace: null
                order: 1
profiles:
    active: vault,git

This is my config server
I followed this doc https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault-lease-renewal but this is not renewing the token.
